# Логика работы шума перлина

Tags: алгоритм

Есть непонимание в объяснение алгоритма работы шума Перлина, а именно точки внутри сетки двухмерного шума, в статьях это называют точкой входа, что это значит и где выход, а также сколько этих точек внутри ячейки сетки, или эта точка есть пиксель значение которого находится интерполяцией, то есть если ячейка имеет размер 10 на 10 пикселей то всего в ячейки 100 таких точек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По этой теме информация немного разрознена + неточность переводов.
Но всё, как мне представляется, просто.

В одномерном случае, нам необходимо для заданного **x** найти значение **y**:

```
function perlinNoise1d(x) {
    // расчет y
    return y;
}
```

Получается, на входе **x**, на выходе **y**.

Для двухмерного случая, по заданной точке **(x, y)** мы рассчитываем значение **z**, которое, при отображении растрового изображения, будет интерпретироваться как интенсивность пикселя:

```
function perlinNoise2d(x, y) {
    // расчет z
    return z;
}
```

Вход: координаты точки **x** и **y**
Выход: **z**

В качестве исходных данных для расчета z используется сетка градиентов, а в основе расчетов: скалярное произведение векторов и интерполяция.

> сколько этих точек внутри ячейки сетки

Бесконечное множество. Функция не является дискретной.

> если ячейка имеет размер 10 на 10 пикселей то всего в ячейки 100 таких
> точек?

Это на экране в ячейке 10x10 будет 100 пикселей.
Здесь же в ячейке бесконечное множество точек. Размер ячейки не имеет значение. Вы можете задать сетку с единичным шагом и искать значения внутри, как непрерывной функции.

Таким образом, мы можем масштабировать шум как угодно и получать шум разной частоты, в том числе, для получения многооктавного шума.

Comment: то есть точке внутри можно привести аналогию как расстояние между двумя точками на оси абсцисс, то есть между значениями x1=1 и x2=2 точка будет вещественным числом в диапазоне [1-2] с неограниченным количеством знаков после запятой?

Comment: насчет двумерного случая в переводах говорится о двух входах и двух выходах, в Вашем же примере два входа и один выход

Comment: "между значениями x1=1 и x2=2 точка будет вещественным числом в диапазоне [1-2] с неограниченным количеством знаков после запятой?" - да, вы получите значение y = f(x) или z = f(x, y) для любых вещественных x и y. При чем в интервале (-∞, +∞) при правильной реализации функции. По поводу двух выходов, что-то тут не так. Дайте ссылку, пожалуйста, посмотрим что там напереводили.

Comment: извиняюсь, не знаю откуда у меня это в голове про два входа-два выхода видимо какой-то когда-то машинный перевод попался. То есть для любых измерений будь то 3х мерное или даже 4х, входов будет по количеству измерений 1 для одномерного 2 для двухмерного 3 для трехмерного и т.д, а выход один-число в диапазоне от -1 до 1, еще хотелось уточнить правила по которым выбираем точку в ячейки или мы их самовольно определяем, например выбираем самый центр ячейки или лежащую прямо на узле, ее роль и значимость до сих пор не ясна, честно говоря.